# Grouping in report builder or linking reports

Tags: combine, report

Can someone help me with one of my reports?
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder but also have access to Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 on wards.

I will use example fields to describe;

I have a set of fields; Client Number, Client Name, Alert1, Alert2, .... , Alert9.

I would like the following grouping;

```
Alert 1
Client Number | Client Name |
Client Number | Client Name |
Client Number | Client Name |
Alert 2
Client Number | Client Name |
Client Number | Client Name |
Client Number | Client Name |
```

The problem I'm having is that because Alerts 1-9 are individual fields, it doesn't allow me to group like the example above.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Is there a way to make combine the alert fields?

Alternatively, is there a way to create a report that can house 9 separate reports via a drop down as follows;

Report: Alerts

Dropdown: Alert 1, Alert 2, ..... , Alert 9

If you clicked Alert 1 it would load the following

```
Alert 1
Client Number | Client Name |
Client Number | Client Name |
Client Number | Client Name |
```

Comment: What software are you using? We cannot answer your question without this essential information. Please [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: Hi David, valid point! Thanks, I have edited the question to reflect what I'm using.